# select code where the price difference is above 8% in the last 3 days

Tags: sql

Here is the table:

| code | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ETH | 2020/1/2 | 1022 |
| ETH | 2020/1/8 | 2000 |
| EOS | 2020/1/4 | 2.3 |
| EOS | 2020/1/9 | 3.2 |

I want to pick up codes whose price changed 8% in the last 3 days.

What I can figure out is something like:

```
select stockcode, 
      LAG(price) over (partition by code order by date) as previous_price 
from table
where (price-previous_price)/previous_price 
order by date
```

But this doesn't work well, any solutions? thanks.

Comment: *But this doesn't work well* - how? Explain how. I don't see anything regarding a percentage in your query? What is *stockcode* in your query? Is this difference the last 3 chronological days or last 3 rows? 8% of what - the last 3 days' average?

Answer (score 0):

try like below using lag() with sub query

```
with cte as
(
select 'e' as c ,'2020-01-02' as d, 1022 as p
union all
select 'e','2020-01-08', 2000
union all
select 'f','2020-01-04',2.3
union all
select 'f','2020-01-09',3.2
),cte2 as 
(select c,p, 
lag(p) over (partition by c order by d) as previous_price,
row_number() over(partition by c order by d) as rn
from cte ) select c  from cte2
where rn!=1
and abs(((p-previous_price)*1.0/p)*100.0)>8
```